# Compiling java program in linux

Tags: java

I have installed openjdk-9-jdk-headless. When I am checking version of the Java then also it gives the appropriate answer. But when I'm compiling any Java program with "$ javac Find.java " it gives:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-5-jdk
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * gcj-4.9-jdk
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Please help how can I compile and run java program.

Comment: Ensure that your javac binary is on the path. edit your path variable $PATH:/opt./../jdk/bin

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that you do not have the Java compiler installed.  It also tells you how to fix this problem.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk-headless
```

(or one of the other packages it offers as alternatives, at your discretion).

The `javac` command is distinct from the `java` command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the path?

```
export PATH=${PATH}:{path to your jdk bin folder here}
```

Or use full path to javac while compiling.

Answer (score 0):

edit your ~/.bashrc and add this to the end 
`JAVA_HOME=opt./../jdk/`
`export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME`

save the ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

Try to compile again

Comment: Wouldn't be `/etc/profile.d/<script>` a better place?

Comment: i wont prefer that but u can also  put inside  the `/etc/environment `